# Eloquent not selecting date attributes when using where clause

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm facing this strange issue with my Eloquent queries.

My model looks like this one:

```
class MyModel extends Model {
    // ...
    $protected $dates = [
    "some_date",
    ]
}
```

When using a query like this one:

```
$myModel = MyModel::find(1);
echo $myModel->toJson();
```

I get this output:

```
{
    "id" : 1
    "some_date" : "../../../"
}
```

But when I use this query:

```
$myModel = MyModel::where('id', '=', 1)->get();
echo $myModel->toJson();
```

I get this strange output:

```
{
    "id" : 1
}
```

The where clause isn't selecting the date attributes! Why is it happening?

Comment: do your date columns have the correct data type?

Comment: What columns do you have for the `$hidden` and `$visible` arrays on the model?

Comment: I'm not using any $visible or $hidden attributes in my models.

Comment: Looks like the BaseModel contains hidden attributes matching the ones I'm using. Now it works. You can post your Comment as an Answer so I validate it.

Comment: Try this:

    $myModels = MyModel::where('id', '=', 1)->get();
    
    foreach($myModels as $myModel)
    {
    echo $myModel->toJson();
    }

Comment: This is just an FYI but when you `echo` an `Eloquent` model you don't need to add `->toJson()` as models and collections have a `__toString()` method which will automatically call this for you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either one of two ways to do this:

If there is a `$hidden` array defined on the model, make sure it does not include this column.

--OR--

If there is no `$hidden` array, make sure there is no `$visible` array and if there is a `$visible` array defined make sure the columns you want are in it.

Laravel removes columns that are hidden or not visible when serializing to json.